# How do I properly convert the file to UTF-16LE encoding without strange characters appearing in the file?

Tags: vim, character-encoding, dictionary

I'm having some peculiarities with the dictionary file of .dsl format I'm trying to convert. It's essentially a text file with the dictionary pairs. The dictionary software I use is GoldenDict. It requires UTF-16 dictionaries so they render properly.

All the dictionaries I have are UTF-16LE format. There is one standing out however. It has iso-8859-1 encoding. An entry looks like this when I open it with vim:

```
abandonarse
    [m2][c crimson][b]Sinónimos[/b][/c][/m]
    [m2][i][c green]verbo[/c][/i][/m]
    [m1][trn][b]desanimarse:[/b] <<desanimarse>>, <<abatirse>>, <<tumbarse>>, <<plegarse>>, <<entregarse>>, <<desligarse>>[/trn][/m]
```

I have to convert it to UTF-16LE because Goldendict renders some Cyrillic characters instead of Spanish accented characters.
Then I try:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-16le dictionary.dsl -o test.dsl
```

The new test.dsl dictionary is rendered correctly by Goldendict, however I can see some peculiar things I would love to get rid of. First is that the just converted file's encoding is not recognized as it usually is with the other dictionaries:

```
    aleksandr@desktop:~/windoc/Dic/Es extra/dictionary.dsl> file dictionary.dsl
dictionary: data
```

When I open the file test.dsl with vim every character inside has ^@ added to it. Here is the example of the same entry:

```
    ^@<^@<^@e^@n^@t^@r^@e^@g^@a^@r^@s^@e^@>^@>^@,^@ ^@<^@<^@d^@e^@s^@l^@i^@g^@a^@r^@s^@e^@>^@>^@[^@/^@t^@r^@n^@]^@[^@/^@m^@]^@
^@      ^@[^@m^@2^@]^@[^@c^@ ^@c^@r^@i^@m^@s^@o^@n^@]^@[^@b^@]^@A^@n^@t^@ó^@n^@i^@m^@o^@s^@[^@/^@b^@]^@[^@/^@c^@]^@[^@/^@m^@]^@
^@      ^@[^@m^@2^@]^@[^@i^@]^@[^@c^@ ^@g^@r^@e^@e^@n^@]^@v^@e^@r^@b^@o^@[^@/^@c^@]^@[^@/^@i^@]^@[^@/^@m^@]^@
```

I tried removing this characters in vim

```
%s/<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-J>//g
```

However, then I save the file, it has the encoding iso-8859-1 again.
I would like to have this file to be show without ^@ characters, because I may need to edit some headings in the dictionary manually.

Comment: The real question here is _How do I get VIM to correctly recognize my text file as UTF-16LE (or ucs2-le) when the file does not have a BOM?_, `iconv` not adding BOMs when it is explicitly told the endinanness to use.

Comment: _How do I get `file` to correctly recognize my text file as UTF-16LE when the file does not have a BOM?_ is really a separate question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `vim` hasn't recognised the encoding, and is showing the 16-bit characters as 8-bit characters. The `^@` markers represent the higher order 8-bits, which for common Latin characters will be zero valued.

You can type this after reading in the file to force recognition of UTF-16LE

```
:e ++enc=utf-16le
```

<sup>(Credit: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12970395/2344631))</sup>

It seems that this would also work, but whether it's ideal is far from clear to me

```
vim -c 'e ++enc=utf-16le' dictionary.dsl
```

Finally, from your [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608452/how-do-i-properly-convert-the-file-to-utf-16le-encoding-without-strange-characte/608455?noredirect=1#comment1135856_608455) it seems that a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) would be quite acceptable. You [can't use `iconv`](https://superuser.com/a/381132/332907) to add a BOM but you can [add one yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365180/2344631)

```
(
    printf "%s" $'\xFF\xFE'
    iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-16le dictionary.dsl
) > dictionary-utf16le.dsl
```

Confirm with

```
file dictionary-utf16le.dsl
dictionary-utf16le.dsl: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text
```